# How do I loop to the top in C++? Could you show me an example?

Tags: c++

I'm trying to make my calcuator loop back to the top after it finishes the calculation? I've tried while loops and seen tutorials on it but I just can't put it into context.

If you could show me how to actually use it in this program, that would be fantastic.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
  double num1, num2;
  char op;
  cout << "********C++ CALCULATOR********" << endl;
  cout << "Please enter your first number" << endl;
  cin  >> num1;
  cout << "Please enter your operand (+, -, *, /)\n" << endl;
  cin  >> op;
  cout << "Please enter your second number\n" << endl;
  cin  >> num2;
  if (op== '+') {
    cout << "The answer is: " << num1 + num2 << endl;
  } else if (op == '-') {
    cout << "The answer is: " << num1 - num2 << endl;
  } else if (op == '/') {
    cout << "The answer is: " << num1 / num2 << endl;
  } else if (op == '*') {
    cout << "The answer is: " << num1 * num2 << endl;
  } else {
    cout << "That was an invalid command!" << endl;
  }
}
```

Comment: I basically just did

while ('10'=='10)
{

//code here

}

Comment: @AlanKong: No, you did't. You should show us your _actual_ attempt. We don't (read: _shouldn't_) simply provide free solutions for you here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For something that you want to run at least once you can also try a do/while statement.

In place of the word "do" you could use  the 'while (again!='n');' at that loops lines curly brace (removing that "while again!='n';" check in the process) to have a standard while loop.

```
while(value==true) { ... }
```

as opposed to

```
do { ... } while(value==true);
```

This would require a properly initialized test variable though.

I included a second while loop  in the larger do/while loop for further demonstration.

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
double num1 = 0, num2 = 0;
char op;
char again;

do {  // set start point for loop
cout << "********C++ CALCULATOR********" << endl;
cout << "Please enter your first number" << endl;
cin  >> num1;
cout << "Please enter your operand (+, -, *, /)" << endl;
cin  >> op;
cout << "Please enter your second number" << endl;
cin  >> num2;

if (op == '+') {
cout << "The answer is: " << num1 + num2 << endl;
} else if (op == '-') {
cout << "The answer is: " << num1 - num2 << endl;
} else if (op == '/') {
cout << "The answer is: " << num1 / num2 << endl;
} else if (op == '*') {
cout << "The answer is: " << num1 * num2 << endl;
} else {
cout << "That was an invalid command!" << endl;
}

cout << "\nRun again? \"y\" or \"n\"" << endl; // prompt user
cin  >> again;

// here is a while loop in do/while statement to check for valid input if the user wants
// to go again 
while(again!='y' && again!='n'){
cout << "Invalid input. Run again? y or n" << endl;
cin >> again;
}

cout << endl;

} while(again!='n'); // now check if user wants to go again // end of do loop
// the condition for while loop could be like
// while (1); // any non zero being true
// if you want executions until program termination

}

}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you want anything like this:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
  double num1 = 0, num2 = 0;
  char op = '';
  char answer = '';
  while(answer != 'n') {  // Check condition
    cout << "********C++ CALCULATOR********" << endl;
    cout << "Please enter your first number" << endl;
    cin  >> num1;
    cout << "Please enter your operand (+, -, *, /)" << endl;
    cin  >> op;
    cout << "Please enter your second number\n" << endl;
    cin  >> num2;
    if (op == '+') {
      cout << "The answer is: " << num1 + num2 << endl;
    } else if (op == '-') {
      cout << "The answer is: " << num1 - num2 << endl;
    } else if (op == '/') {
      cout << "The answer is: " << num1 / num2 << endl;
    } else if (op == '*') {
      cout << "The answer is: " << num1 * num2 << endl;
    } else {
      cout << "That was an invalid command!\n Exit." << endl;
    }
    cout << "Do you want repeat? \"y\" or \"n\"\n" << endl;
    cin  >> answer;
  }
}
```

The while construct consists of a block of code and a condition. The condition is evaluated, and if the condition is true, the code within the block is executed. This repeats until the condition becomes false. Because while loop checks the condition before the block is executed, the control structure is often also known as a pre-test loop. Compare with the do while loop, which tests the condition after the loop has executed.

Answer (score 0):

Just wrap everything into an endless loop

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    for (;;) {

        // your code here
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you explain to me what a for loop means?

Comment: For loop looks like "for (initialization; condition; increment-decrement) {/*body*/}".
initialization - happen only one times - when you enter in loop.
condition - is the rule which checked every new iteration.
increment-decrement - modification of your iteration variable.
Body - code which repeats.

For example following loop:
for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
  cout << i;
}
will print you "0123456789".

Comment: @AlanKong: You should consult your book.